# how to check if the lists in a list have the same length

Tags: java, list

I have a list of lists in Java. Here is the code:

```
List<List<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

myList.get(0).add(1);
myList.get(0).add(2);
myList.get(0).add(3);
myList.get(1).add(4);
myList.get(1).add(5);
myList.get(1).add(6);
myList.get(2).add(7);
myList.get(2).add(8);
myList.get(2).add(9);
```

How to check if the lists that exist in myList have the same length? I know that I can check the length of each list by something like `myList.get(0).size()`, so what is an efficient and short way to check if all these lists have the same length (instead of checking one by one)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `Stream.allMatch()` by matching any contained list size (for example the first one) with all other contained lists :

```
boolean isSameLength = 
myList.stream()
      .allMatch(l -> l.size() == myList.get(0).size())
```

It makes the first comparison helpless as it compares the same contained list but it is more readable that :

```
boolean isSameLength = 
myList.stream()
      .skip(1)
      .allMatch(l -> l.size() == myList.get(0).size())
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hope to say that *n* lists have the same length without visiting them. You **have** to go one-by-one. davidxxx's answer shows a really nice way with streams but visits all the lists anyway. The naive way may be

```
public static boolean sameLength(List<List> lists){
    if(lists.get(0) == null){ //EDIT: as davidxxx pointed out this if is superfluous
        return true;
    }
    int len = lists.get(0).size();
    for (List list : lists) {
        if(list.size() != len){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My IDE even suggests using functional operators with the above code like davidxxx said.

Comment: Good answer. But I think that the first check `if(lists.get(0) == null){
        return true;
    }` is not required because to be consistent you should do it for every contained lists and besides checking null is actually not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks - the streams are more readable and optimization in this case does not make much sense, but they run a little bit longer (for a very long `List`). The null check - this would still crash if `lists` is null, but I thought that I may want to return `true` for an empty list - since across 0 lists, they all have the same length. Maybe `if(lists.isEmpty())` would make more sense.

Comment: You are welcome :)  A list may have null elements at some indexes and not null values at the next indexes. So `lists.get(0) == null` seems to be too specific.  `if(lists.isEmpty())` would make more sense but well if there is not any contained list, it means no iteration. So no optimization.  :)

Comment: Of course - you're right. In this form neither check makes any sense (I did not consider the case that there is a `null` at `0` and a valid `Integer` at `1`). I wonder if you should write null checks (for example inside the foreach) or just say that an exception will be thrown if the `List` contains `null`?

Comment: according to the OP example, the null case is not possible, so as said in my first comment I just would ignore that. In a general way, performing null check is better than leaving an exception rises if the case is known and may be handled . An exception is an exceptional thing to signal a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, you can use lambda expressions to simplify your application. Look:

```
if (myList.stream().filter(integers -> integers.size() == myList.get(0).size()).count() == myList.size()) {
    System.out.println("The sub-lists have the same size");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
listOfList.stream().map(list -> list.size()).distinct().count() == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check using a counter variable, iterate your `myList` and get the size of `sublist`. If size of `myList`== `sublist` then assign `true` else assign `false` like following:

```
public static boolean isSameLength(List<List<Integer>> myList) {
    boolean isSame = false;
    for (List<Integer> sublist : myList) {
        if (sublist.size() == myList.size()) {
            isSame = true;
        } else {
            isSame = false;
        }
    }
    return isSame;
}
```

Comment: `if (sublist.size() == myList.size()) {` is helpless. What you want to detect is "if the sizes differ". Besides you can exit from the loop as soon as this condition is detected. You don't need to have a boolean flag.

Comment: @davidxxx boolean flag is needed because we need to override the result at each iteration.

Comment: @SudhirOjha `sublist.size() == myList.size()` means you compare the parent list size with every child list. its not he wants. he wants to check if all sublists have same size or not ?

Comment: So how will you do this without using stream ?

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha The answer of Raven shows the way of doing it without stream : no flag is required.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following:

```
myList.stream()
    .map(e -> e.size())
    .distinct()
    .limit(2)  // optimization
    .count() == 1;
```

Basically checking if there are any 2 lists with a different size.